# Mod Rewrite for catalog website

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have four files:

`store.php` -> as the **listing for all products** (paginated as ?pag={page number})

`category-listing.php` -> as the listing for **category products**,ex: `?catid=1` (also has pagination same as store.php)

`subcategory-listing.php` -> listing for **subcategory products**, ex: `?subcatid=1` (has pagination)

And the product detail page,
`product-detail.php` -> will have product title and id

This is what i want:

```
www.mysite.com/store/ or www.mysite.com/store/?pag=2

www.mysite.com/store/category/ or www.mysite.com/store/category/?pag=2

www.mysite.com/store/subcategory/ or www.mysite.com/store/subcategory/?pag=2

www.mysite.com/store/a-product-detail-1 -> product detail (title and id)
```

Keep in mind the except the product detail all the other files are paginated as ?pag={pagenumber}

How can i do this?

This what i got so far for subcategories but pagination is not working

```
RewriteRule ^/store/%1? [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /subcategory\.php\?subcatid=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^store/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ subcategory.php?subcatid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: OK, fine. However you did not really ask a specific question... The answer to the extremely general question "How can i do this?" is of course "by implementing rewrite rules as required". So what is your _specific_ question here, assuming that you read into the topic and made your own attempts but failed?

Comment: You are right. I updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. So what you have to take care of is the `pag=...` part of the request, right? Why doesn't the `QSA` flag you already use for the last rule work for the subcategories pagination?

Comment: Yes, do you mind showing me an example maybe as an answer?

Comment: An example adding the `QSA` flag you already use yourself in another rule? Well... Just change `[NC]` to `[NC,QSA]`, I'd say...

Comment: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /subcategory\.php\?subcatid=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) [NC,QSA], like this?